# Using Lucene.Net_2_9_1/contrib/Spatial.Net with Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net, geospatial

I've tried doing this with Umbraco 6.1.6. I've pretty much implemented what Drew did here:  http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/23200-Lucene-with-spatialnet?p=0

I'm storing lat and long data in umbraco nodes. The nodes are being indexed as encided values with tiers. But, I am not returning any results when I add the DistanceFilter to the query.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has tried this and got it working. Perhaps you can post some code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Josh,

Have you inspected the index using luke just to ensure that fields are there? Also have you tried running raw queries (get the generated query written out using code) on the index using luke?

Regards

Ismail